# Using a CListCtrl with Drag and Drop not working

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

Using *Visual Studio 2017* I am trying to enable drag and drop on a `CListCtrl`, I have added the code for this such as:

```
ON_WM_DROPFILES()

DragAcceptFiles();
m_listctrl.DragAcceptFiles();


void ProgramNameHere::OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo)
{
CString sFile;
DWORD   nBuffer = 0;

// Get the number of files dropped
int nFilesDropped = DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, 0xFFFFFFFF, NULL, 0);

for (int i = 0; i<nFilesDropped; i++)
{
    // Get the buffer size of the file.
    nBuffer = DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, i, NULL, 0);

    // Get path and name of the file
    DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, i, sFile.GetBuffer(nBuffer + 1), nBuffer + 1);
    sFile.ReleaseBuffer();

    MessageBox(PathFindFileName(sFile), PathFindFileName(sFile));
}

    // Free the memory block containing the dropped-file information
    DragFinish(hDropInfo);

    CDialogEx::OnDropFiles(hDropInfo);
}
```

I am able to get it working when I drop a file onto the dialog itself anywhere but when I try and drop it onto the List Control it doesn't work.

Would anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you've enabled drag n drop for the dialog, but, not for the control itself.

Comment: How would i achieve this?

Comment: You derive your own class from CListCtrl and handle the drop message.

Comment: DragAcceptFiles(); // Adds Drag and drop to the whole dialog
m_listctrl.DragAcceptFiles(); // Adds DnD to the particulat contol.

When you drag a file and try to drop over your control the message is enrouted too the dialog and not the control. Remove the first line i.e. "DragAcceptFiles(); ".